Could not find org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006
In my application I am using webrtc sdk but facing an issue, any help will really helpfull.
implementation("org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006")

It syncing properly but while showing error of could not Could not find org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006.
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
        maven { url = uri("https://www.jitpack.io" ) }

    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url = uri("https://www.jitpack.io" ) }

    }
}

I have already tried to downgrade but nothing works.
some people saying to use other library like
implementation 'com.infobip:google-webrtc:1.0.0035529'
implementation 'com.dafruits:webrtc:123.0.0'

I have tried to downgrade the version
Rebuild
invalidate cache restart


Any luck? I have facing same issue. on my end the version is org.webrtc.google-webrtc:1.0.28513

@MohitLakhanpal I have implemented "implementation("com.infobip:google-webrtc:1.0.0035529")" this for temporary fix, and till now its working fine with all usage.
